# CSS width property: what unit will it use if it is not specified?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table's HTML content like something below where the unit of style.width is missing. I tried using 153px, 153pt, and 153 in Chrome and Firefox, and they all result into different width. I am wondering what exact unit it is using when there is no unit specified?

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;width:153">...</table>
```